# How to show both the URL and URL title in the modal dialog?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on 'add a link' functionality. For that I'm using Modal plugin from Twitter Boostrap JS. On the main page there's only the 'link' field to fill, when a user clicks 'add link' button, a modal pops up, and the user sees the complete form to fill 3 fields: link, title, tags. However, I want 1) the link field to be pre-filled with the value from the previous step AND 2) the title field is pre-filled with the title of the url.

I can do each of these separately, but I can't do both. In fact, the code below pre-fills the link field leaving title field empty. If I uncomment the AJAX part and add 'onClick="sendRequest()', then the code prefills the title field by executing the php script 'savePostAjax.php' which given the url echoes the title. However, in that case the link field is not filled. I guess, Bootstrap  events somehow interfere with AJAX I wrote. One approach I tried is to get the url title in JavaScript, didn't work. How would you go about solving this problem of pre-filling BOTH link and title of the form in the modal dialog? Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />

<!-- AJAX 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajaxwebform/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function sendRequest() {
        new Ajax.Request("savePostAjax.php",
        {
            method: 'post',
            parameters: 'linkURL='+$F('linkURL'),
            onComplete: showResponse
        });
    }
    function showResponse(req){
        $('show-title').value= req.responseText;
    }
    </script>
    AJAX ENDS -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $('#modal-from-dom').bind('show',function()
                {
                    $(".modal-body #wall-post").val($("#linkURL").val());
                });
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- The Modal Dialog  -->
          <div id="modal-from-dom" class="modal hide fade">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
                <h3>Add Link</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

<!-- onsubmit='return false;' -->
            <form id='post-on-wall' method='POST' action='savePost.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'  >
                <div>
                <input id='show-title' class='label-inline' name='title' type='text' size='100'>                
                </div>
                <div>
                <input id='wall-post' class='label-inline' name='linkURL' type='text' size='100'>
                </div>
                <div>
                <input id='link-field' class='label-inline' name='topics' type='text' size='100' placeholder='topics'>
                </div>
            </form>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn primary">Add Link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
  <!-- Enf of The Modal Dialog  -->    
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wall-post">
        <input id='linkURL' class='label-inline' name='linkURL' type='text' size='100' autocomplete='off'>
        <button data-controls-modal="modal-from-dom" data-backdrop="true" data-keyboard="true" class="btn">Add Link</button>
<!-- onClick="sendRequest()" -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why not use jQuery to send the ajax request as well? You could stick the sendRequest code inside the 'show' bind that way, and you'd have one less library.

Comment: Thanks, Jerry! I actually don't have much experience writing jQuery, could you show how I can 'stick the sendRequest code inside the show bind' specifically?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is because you've included prototype and jquery, both of which try to occupy $. You can easily get around this by using jQuery in noConflict mode but I'd recommend ditching prototype completely as it doesn't make sense to use two libraries in that situation.

I haven't actually run this, but it should be what you need. Of course before actually using it you'll want to add a little spinner indicating that the ajax request is being made etc.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    function setTitle(url) {
        $.post("savePostAjax.php", { linkURL: $('#linkURL').val() },
            function(resp) {
            $('show-title').val= resp;
        });
    };

    $('#modal-from-dom').bind('show',function() {
        var linkURL = $('#linkURL').val();
        $('.modal-body #wall-post').val(linkURL);
        setTitle(linkURL);
    });
});
```